# What's this outlet on the wing of Eurofighter Typhoon EF2000 for?

Tags: aircraft-design, fighter, eurofighter-typhoon

I was seeing [this image](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/10235096) and saw this outlet.

[image]

It's not the outlet of an APU, is it?

Comment: Duplicate question confirms, it IS the exhaust for the APU.